# how to export that web3.admin api in external java Script code web3.admin api doesn't work in external JavaScript code

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to interact with a private blockchain from JavaScript code. For that I've provided an RPC address to each node and extended multiple apis using `-rpcapi`. Now if I'm using `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8546` I'm able to use admin apis in new console, but when I use a web3 object with same address, it doesn't recognize admin api.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
let express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8101"));
}

console.log('web3 miner',web3.miner);//here it gives undefined
```

and the command i used to run private blockchain is

```
geth --port 30303 --networkid 58343 --datadir ./datadir --rpc --rpcport 8101 --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" console
```

Comment: its give undefined on web3.admin